# How to iterate a list and add rows dynamically in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to achieve the below scenario using html,CSS,javascript and bootstrap:

If there is a list(size(n) will be dynamic), then i need to create m number of rows with three columns.

So suppose the list size is 12, then i should create 4 rows with 3 columns.

similarly the list size is 15, then i should create 5 rows with 3 columns.

Based on the list count number of rows should be iterated.
Please help me with your inputs whether it is possible or not?

Comment: read about columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 2):

```
ul {
  display: block;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

This should do the trick. but your element will be displayed like this:

```
A  |  B  |  C
D  |  E  |  F
G  |  H  |
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be helpful to you

Assuming your list is single dimensional array of numbers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">
Generate Rows and columns- click me
</p>

<script>


function myFunction() {  
    var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12];
    var count = 0;
    var str = '';
    for (var i=count; i<list.length; i++) {
    debugger;
    count++;
    str += list[i] + '  ' + '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp';
    if(count === 3) {
    count = 0;
    str += '</br>'
    }
    
    }
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
    }



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you will click the

tag you will get the output as what you required, hope you can do the CSS styling part of it yourself.

[image]